# SOAP UI - how to pass Current date time json in UTC format and RFC 7231 format in the header

Tags: json, soap

I am using SOAP UI and submitting a JSON submission. However I am not sure how to submit so that the current date/time is automatically populated like for the JSON body field as below

"receivedDateTime":"2020-09-10T07:40:00.001Z"

I tried the following for a similar field as above

"preparationDateTime":"${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(new java.util.Date())}", but I don't think it works

HEADER

I have been able to set up the current UTC format for one of the dates in the header but that's UTC format

${= new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") }

but another date in the header date/time needs to be in RFC7231 format - Thu, 01 Oct 2020 13:30:23 GMT
so not sure how to do this?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

For RFC7231 format, you can use

"preparationDateTime":"${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'").format(new java.util.Date())}"new SimpleDateFormat("").format(new Date())

Aforementioned date format will return "Thu, 19 Nov 2020 18:39:01 GMT"